# IOS/Objective-C: Animate Image Change in UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to create an effect where a custom image in a UIBarButtonItem changes to another image.  So far, I have been able to get the first image to dissolve with the following code.  Can anyone suggest how I could get the second image to fade in at the same time?

```
//Create barbuttonitem in viewwillappear
UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [b setFrame:CGRectMake(12, 0, 22, 22)];
    [b addTarget:self action:@selector(menuButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [b setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"firstimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem * myBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:b];

//Animate in viewDidAppaer

 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:1.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         self.myBarButton.customView.alpha = 0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
UIImage *secondImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu2.png"];
    [self.myBarButton setImage:secondImage];//THis does not change image
                                 self.myBarButton.customView.alpha = 1;//no animation
                             }];
```

Comment: when you want to change image?

Comment: I would like the second image to fade in as the first one fades out.  The completion block is probably not an ideal place for the second image to fade in the fade in should start before the fade out ends.

Comment: can you add full code?

Comment: that is the full code that I have so far

Comment: pls check i added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.myBarButton
                      duration:0.3
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{ [self.myBarButton setImage:secondImage];}
                    completion:nil];
```

Comment: I think you mean self.myBarButton.customView....  However, nothing happens just as I could not set the barButton image in my line above  [self.myBarButton setImage:secondImage];//THis does not change image.  I think to change the image in a barbutton you need to do something more involved as barbutton does not inherit from UIView

Comment: In your code you are changing the image in completion block. That would surely not result in any animation. Try moving that code to the animation block as i have done. Also since you are adding a custom button in the BarButtonItem, either make a property of that custom button or access it using viewWithTag: on barbutton's customView. That is the button whose image should be changed.

Comment: so not [self.myBarButton setImage...]  but  [self.b setImage...]?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code    

    @interface ViewController ()
        {
            UIBarButtonItem * myBarButton;
            NSTimer *time;
            UIButton *b;
        }
        @end

        @implementation ViewController

        - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [b setFrame:CGRectMake(12, 0, 22, 22)];
            [b addTarget:self action:@selector(menuButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [b setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"AddPlus_Yellow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            myBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:b];
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=myBarButton;
            time = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2.0 target: self selector:@selector(onTick:) userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        -(void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer {

            [b setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"filter.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[time invalidate];

        }
```